# Theorem without numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems

Is it possible to have single theorems without numbering? I would like to be able to switch them off individually with asterisk-* or have a nono-theorem environment.

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{nono-theorem}{Theorem}[]
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Using the `amsthm` package, you can switch numbering on and off for individual theorems just by defining environments with nearly identical names (as with equation environments):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}  A numbered theorem.    \end{theorem}
\begin{theorem*} An unnumbered theorem. \end{theorem*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a question, and I didn't want to open another topic of the same type. I have defined, like here the definition, but when I use it I have a dot afterwards. Like: Definition. Bla bla bla...
How to get rid of that dot?

Comment: @dingo_d: Check out the [`\newtheoremstyle`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Theorems#Custom_styles) command provided by the `amsthm` package; that will allow you to define new "styles" for theorems (e.g. change the punctuation, as you're asking for) in a reasonably flexible way.

Comment: @ Niel de Beaudrap: After a bit of searching (like few min after I posted this) I found that I can very easily manipulate with much more than just dot or no dot in the theorem environment :D So the problem is solved :D

Comment: thanks, very helpfull!

Answer (score 18):

(It's more of a comment.)

You can define a  new theorem with a star:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem*{theorem-non}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\begin{theorem-non}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem-non}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative I've used goes as follows. Include this at the top of your file:

```
\def\theorem{\par\noindent{\bf Theorem.\ } \ignorespaces}
\def\endtheorem{}
```

Then create a theorem with:

```
\begin{theorem}

\end{theorem}
```

Nice for things like

```
\def\problemstatement{\par\noindent{\bf Problem Statement.\ } \ignorespaces}
\def\endproblemstatement{}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\bBox}{\hbox{\vrule width1.3ex height1.3ex}}
\def\proof{\par\noindent{\bf Proof.\ } \ignorespaces}
\def\endproof{{\ \hspace*{\fill}\bBox \parfillskip 0pt}\smallskip\noindent}
```