# How to create an unnumbered theorem?

Tags: numbering, environments, theorems

I'm looking for a way to create a new theorem without numbering. I found [Theorem without numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30033/theorem-without-numbering) and tried the accepted answer, but I get the error "Command * already defined".

This is the code I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}

\newtheorem*{hulprule}{Rule settings}
\newenvironment{drule}[3]
    {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]\begin{hulprule}\begin{enumerate}[-]
                    \item \textbf{Events}:{#1}
                    \item \textbf{Conditions}:{#2}
                    \item \textbf{Actions}:{#3}}
    {\end{enumerate}\end{hulprule}\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{drule}
        {test}
        {test}
        {test}
    \end{drule}

\end{document}
```

Strangely enough, the *drule* environment works perfectly without the `*`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have to load `amsthm` for `\newtheorem*`

Comment: @egreg: Outch, overlooked that. Stupid. That's the solution, it works now! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it at once! :)

Comment: Why an environment? It should be a command with three arguments.

Comment: @egreg: Well, I didn't have the 3 arguments first (that's why I'm working with an environment), but as every enumeration has to start with those 3 words, I had to work with arguments. Maybe there's a better way to achieve this, but I'm a bit of a newbie... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `\usepackage{amsthm}`. I'd improve the definition, though, with `enumitem` instead of `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,enumitem,xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

\newtheorem*{hulprule}{Rule settings}
\newenvironment{drule}[3]
 {\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=lightgray]%
  \begin{hulprule}\leavevmode
  \begin{itemize}[label=\textbf{--},itemindent=-1em]
    \item \textbf{Events}: #1
    \item \textbf{Conditions}: #2
    \item \textbf{Actions}: #3}
 {\end{itemize}%
  \end{hulprule}%
  \end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{drule}
  {test}
  {test}
  {test}
  \item something else
  \item another
\end{drule}

\end{document}
```

A simple hyphen should never be used for marking an item; over a grey background a dash becomes barely noticeable, so it's better to boldface it. Adjust the `itemindent` to suit.

[image]

Comment: That's absolutely perfect. You're immediately countering my next question about how I can start the enumeration after the 'Rule settings' title!