# Environment formatting: how to display the name of an axiom instead of its counter number

Tags: formatting, environments, theorems, newtheorem

I am using the following environment to write axioms in my thesis

```
\theoremstyle{definition}  
\newtheorem{myax}{Axiom}
```

As expected, if I write

```
\beging{myax}[Axiom of Choice]
\end{myax}
```

I get

**Axiom 1**(Axiom of Choice)

I was wondering if I could display bold the text in [ ], hiding the rest (Axiom 1)

Thanks in advance

**I am using the folllowing code**

```
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{myprop}[myth]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{mylemma}[myth]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{myax}{Axiom}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{myrmk}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{myex}{Example}[section]
```

**Code with ntheorem**

```
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{. }
%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{emptybreak}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
\newtheorem{myax}
%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{myprop}[myth]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{mylemma}[myth]{Lemma}
%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{remark}
{\item[\hskip\labelsep\theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\theorem@separator]}
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{remark}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{myrmk}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{myex}{Example}[section]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoresymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{myth}{Theorem}
\crefalias{Myth}{myth}
\crefname{myprop}{Proposition}
\crefalias{Myprop}{myprop}
\crefname{mylemma}{Lemma}
\crefalias{Mylemma}{mylemma}
\crefname{mydef}{Definition}
\crefalias{Mydef}{mydef}
\crefname{myrmk}{Remark}
\crefalias{Myrmk}{myrmk}
\crefname{myex}{Example}
\crefalias{Myex}{myex}
\crefname{myax}{Axiom}
\crefalias{Myax}{myax}

\begin{document}
\begin{myth}
 My theorem.
\end{myth}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy with `ntheorem` which defines the `empty` and `emptybreak`styles. These styles define no counter nor header: only the optional argument is printed.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{empty}
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape} 
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
\newtheorem{named}{}

\theoremstyle{emptybreak}
\newtheorem{namedbreak}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{named}[Axiom of choice. ] If $X$ is a set of nonempty sets, there exists a function $f$ on $X$ such that, for any $A\in X$, one has $f(A)\in A$.
\end{named}

\begin{namedbreak}[Dr Faustroll’s axiom]
  God is the tangential point of $0$ and $\infty$.
\end{namedbreak}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: To have the same layout with `ntheorem` as with the basic styles of `amsthm`, use this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{. }

%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{empty}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
\newtheorem{named}{}

\theoremstyle{emptybreak}
\newtheorem{namedbreak}{}
%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{myprop}[myth]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{mylemma}[myth]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\makeatletter
 \newtheoremstyle{remark}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{remark}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{myrmk}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{myex}{Example}[section]
```

*Edit*: I cleaned your last code and made it fully functional. In particular, when you declare a theorem structure, say `mytheorem`, with the `empty` style, you have to write `\newtheorem{mytheorem}{}`(with a last empty argument).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[amsmath,thref, thmmarks]{ntheorem}%
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theoremseparator{. }
%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{emptybreak}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}
\newtheorem{myax}{}
%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{plain}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{myprop}[myth]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{mylemma}[myth]{Lemma}
%%%%%%%%%%%
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\newtheorem{mydef}{Definition}[section]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{remark}
{\item[\hskip\labelsep\theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\theorem@separator]}
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textup{##2}\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{remark}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{myrmk}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{myex}{Example}[section]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath\square}
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{myth}{Theorem}{Theorems}
\crefalias{Myth}{myth}
\crefname{myprop}{Proposition}{Propositions}
\crefalias{Myprop}{myprop}
\crefname{mylemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefalias{Mylemma}{mylemma}
\crefname{mydef}{Definition}{Definitions}
\crefalias{Mydef}{mydef}
\crefname{myrmk}{Remark}{Remarks}
\crefalias{Myrmk}{myrmk}
\crefname{myex}{Example}{Examples}
\crefalias{Myex}{myex}
\crefname{myax}{Axiom}{Axioms}
\crefalias{Myax}{myax}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydef}
 \textbf{Egotist}, n. A person of low taste, more interested in him\-self than in me.
\end{mydef}
\begin{myth}
 My theorem.
\end{myth}

\begin{proof}
 \[ \text{Fiddle dee dee!} \]
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually I thought yours was the solution but I am having some problems: if I use \ntheorem together with \amsthm there is a conflict. I tried to change everything to \ntheorem, following the package intrsuction, but all of my code is written in \amsthm: the compiler signals somethig like 270 errors! The code I am using is the one I added to the question: do you know how to replace it?

Comment: In  general, it's not very hard, but may take some time verifying all layout details. I'll look at your code and make some tests before I propose a code.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Actually I did click on the button, but I forgot to check there was a  blank line inserted at the beginning of the code. Thanks!

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta: I've added a code to obtain the same layout as `amsthm`. I has to define a `remark` style, as the header font being italic resulted in remarks numbers also being italic.  I didn't define a `proof` environment, as you didn't define one, but if you need it, feel free to ask.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta: You can achive what you want via `amsthm` too: see, for example, [Theorem without numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30033/69818).

Comment: @Gum: But can it also easily display only the optional argument?

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, it can (I’ve just checked).  **Edit:**  But wait a minute, what do you mean by “only”?

Comment: Nothing before the optional argument, so the same environment will be used to type *Axiom of choice* or *Nullstellensatz* or *Principal ideal theorem*.

Comment: @Bernard: Yes, of course!  Mine was a stupid question.  Well, the manual of the `amsthm` package recommends defining a different environment for each named theorem (`AC`, `nullst`, or `ZL` for “Zorn’s lemma”, and so on).  Of course, you can always resort to using `\newtheoremstyle` and exploiting its last argument.

Comment: @Bernard I am really grateful! The output looks like I imagined. Only problem is the compiler signals  begin{document} missing plus extra } in myth. And I really cannot understand why...

Comment: The last code I posted was only a code to be included in your preamble, and the coding of `myth` is normal. Could you please a minimal code reproducing the problem, or a link to?

Comment: @Bernard, sure! I re edited the question: the only thing I changed with respect to your code was defining a proof environment and the \Cleveref commands to make references work. NOotice that Definitions, Example, Remark, Axiom work really well.

Comment: @FrancescoBilotta: I've cleaned your code. Your error was to forget the last argument in declaring `myax` (even empty, it's mandatory). A second error was with the declaration of `\cref`: the plural forms were missing. B.t.w.  what you declared, really, should be for `\Cref`, not `cref`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `amsthm` (better than `ntheorem`, in my opinion).

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{inneraxiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem*{inneraxiomnonumber}{\axiomname}
\providecommand{\axiomname}{}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{axiom}{o}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\inneraxiom}% no optional argument, nothing special
    {% optional argument
     \renewcommand{\axiomname}{#1}% set \axiomname to #1
     \def\@currentlabel{#1}% for \ref
     \inneraxiomnonumber% start the unnumbered environment
    }%
 }
 {\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\endinneraxiom}{\endinneraxiomnonumber}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}\label{axiom:standard}
This is a standard axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}[Francesco's axiom]\label{axiom:francesco}
All axioms are useful.
\end{axiom}

\cref{axiom:standard}

\ref{axiom:francesco}

\end{document}
```

It makes little sense to use `\cref` for named axioms.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`amsthm` provides a starred version of `\newtheorem` that substitutes the specified argument for the usual numbered heading.  So this definition would produce the heading you want:

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{axch}{Axiom of Choice}
```

Of course, the heading is now fixed, so if a different "specific" heading is wanted, a separate `\newtheorem*` is needed.

This is described on page 3 of the `amsthm` user guide (`texdoc amsthdoc`).

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that this question has been reopened, I’ve thought that, after all, I could elaborate on [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506485/environment-formatting-how-to-display-the-name-of-an-axiom-instead-of-its-count#comment1279738_506491) and offer a solution that relies only on the `amsthm` package.

As Barbara Beeton has already remarked in [her answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506563/69818), the *-form of the `\newtheorem` command does not create a counter associated with the environment being defined, and so yields theorems (or lemmas, propositions, definitions…) that are not numbered, but are labeled with the text specified in the second argument of the `\newtheorem*` command, unadorned.  For example, it is typical to see in a paper the following declaration:

```
\newtheorem*{MT}{Main Theorem}
```

This creates an environment named `MT` that one uses to state the main result of the paper:

```
\begin{MT}
    My research deserves to be funded.
\end{MT}
```

As already noted by Barbara, this has the drawback (but is it really a drawback?) that you need to define a different environment for each “named” theorem (or axiom, or…) that you want to mention.

Bernard asks in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506485/environment-formatting-how-to-display-the-name-of-an-axiom-instead-of-its-count#comment1279733_506491) whether it is possible to define — using only `amsthm`’s features — an environment for a “generic” unnumbered theorem, that uses, for the label, not the text specified in the second argument of the `\newtheorem*` command, but the contents of the optional argument of the environment itself, *i.e.*, the argument meant to pass an “optional note” for the theorem header.  The answer is affirmative, but you need to define a new “theorem style” by means of the `\newtheoremstyle` declaration.

The `\newtheoremstyle` command is described in Subsection 4.3 of the manual of the `amsthm` package.  In its ninth argument you can indicate how the header that labels the theorem/axiom/… is built from the following three pieces:

1. The theorem’s **name** (*e.g.*, “Theorem”, “Lemma”, “Axiom”…):
   this is the text specified in the second argument
   of the `\newtheorem` (or `\newtheorem*`) command.
2. The theorem’s **number**: this is the current value of the counter
   associated to the environment (more precisely, it is the
   expansion of, say, `\theaxiom`, if `axiom` is the name
   of the counter, which is the same as that of the environment).
3. The theorem’s **optional note**: these are the contents
   of the optional argument of the environment.

More precisely (quoting from `amsclass.dtx`), the ninth argument of `\newtheoremstyle`…

> …is interpreted as the replacement text for an internal three-argument
>   function `\thmhead`, *i.e.*, as if you were defining
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\thmhead}[3]{...#1...#2...#3...}
> ```
>
> but omitting the initial `\renewcommand{\thmhead}[3]`.
>   The three arguments that will be supplied to `\thmhead`
>   are the name, number, and optional note component.

For more information, see the file `amsclass.dtx`.  The above information suffices to see that, for example,

```
\newtheoremstyle{emptyplain}
    {}          % default space above
    {}          % default space below
    {\itshape}  % body font
    {}          % no indent
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {.}         % punctuation after theorem head
    { }         % space after theorem head (normal interword space)
    {#3}        % using "\thmnote{#3}" is redundant, isn't it?
\theoremstyle{emptyplain}
\newtheorem*{namedaxiom}{}
```

does what Bernard asked for: it defines a “generic unnumbered theorem-like” environment that uses, for the the theorem head, the sheer contents of the optional note.

MWE that recaps all what we have being saying:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% I deem axioms should typeset like plain theorems...
% \theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom}
\newtheorem*{AC} {Axiom of Choice}
\newtheorem*{GCH}{Generalized Continuum Hypothesis}

\newtheoremstyle{emptyplain}
    {}          % default space above
    {}          % default space below
    {\itshape}  % body font
    {}          % no indent
    {\bfseries} % theorem head font
    {.}         % punctuation after theorem head
    { }         % space after theorem head (normal interword space)
    {#3}        % using "\thmnote{#3}" is redundant, isn't it?
\theoremstyle{emptyplain}
\newtheorem*{namedaxiom}{}



\begin{document}

A few ``generic'' axioms:

\begin{axiom}[Union set]
    If $x$ and~$y$ are sets, then $x\cup y$ is also a set.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}[Power set]
    If $x$ is a set, then $\wp(x)$ is also a set.
\end{axiom}

A named axiom:

\begin{AC}
    Blah blah blah\ldots
\end{AC}

Another one:

\begin{GCH}[a.k.a.\ Cantor's Aleph Hypothesis]
    For every ordinal~$\alpha$,
    \[ \aleph_{\alpha+1} = 2^{\aleph_{\alpha}} \]
\end{GCH}

With the \texttt{emptyplain} theorem style
(and a statement that spans two lines,
so you can check that there are no stray spaces):

\begin{namedaxiom}[Francesco's Axiom of Axioms]
    All axioms are important, but some axioms are more important than others.
\end{namedaxiom}

\begin{axiom}[benchmark]
    This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

But:

\begin{namedaxiom}
    This axiom is not correctly typeset.
\end{namedaxiom}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image: Output of the code]